# How do I calculate the average when the numbers are grouped

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm building (in Rails) an app to scrape NBA data (mostly for my own edification and a learning tool).  I started with postgresql from scratch because it just makes more sense if I'm going to host with it.  The database schema is set up exactly as I want it [here](https://github.com/jemagee/nba/blob/master/db/schema.rb).

Participant instances are based on a TEAM concept
Statistic instances are based on a PLAYER concept and thus many instances of Statistic make up the 'totals' for participant.

The following query:

```
Select SUM(steals) from statistics
INNER JOIN participants on statistics.participant_id = participants.id
INNER JOIN teams on participants.team_id = teams.id 
WHERE teams.id = 15 
GROUP BY statistics.participant_id;
```

yields (in the psql terminal app)

```
 sum 
-----
   8
   7
   5
   7
   6
   7
  10
   6
   7
   6
   7
   5
   9
  11
   4
   7
   8
```

How do I write the sql query to calculate the average based on these 17 rows

(edit to simplify query and only ask one question)

Comment: @MageeWorld you are close to do what you want.Give it a try and take look at `Aggrigate functions` like `AVG()` for this.

Comment: Use a subselect: `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... GROUP BY ...) s GROUP BY ...`

Comment: @CoderofCode I do know about aggregate functions (though most of my experience is in mysql) but I don't know how to wrap the aggregate query within in an average query

Comment: @MageeWorld - yes you do, SUM is an aggregate function.   It just means it is applied over more than one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query to wrap your query

```
SELECT sum, AVG(sum)
FROM (
  -- your query here
) x
```

on some systems you can also use a windowing function which does not require the outer query.  The syntax for that looks like this

```
AVG(sum) OVER () as avg
```

since the average you are looking for is the result of a grouping you can't use it here.

Comment: what you gave me pointed me in the right direction, though for my needs - this is what worked *Select AVG(sum) FROM ( my query ) as sum;`* (ps - am I doing something wrong or can you not hit 'return' in edits?

Comment: @MageeWorld `SELECT AVG(sum) AS sum FROM ( stuff);` is the more standard way to write it -- but it seems fine.