# Postgres SQL calculate average of calculated totals

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a query to return all products with higher than average dollar sales.  The relevant tables and columns are:

- PRODUCTS: 
  prod_id: integer,
  price:   decimal
- ORDERLINES:
  prod_id:  integer,
  quantity: integer

I can write the subquery that gets dollar sales for each product, but I'm having trouble applying the average function to that subquery.  Everything I try returns a syntax error.  Following is what I thought should be close to the answer:

```
select avg(sum) as avg_sales 
from (
   select sum(b.quantity * a.price) as total_sales 
   from products a, orderlines b 
   where a.prod_id = b.prod_id 
   group by a.prod_id
);
```

When I try this, I get:

> ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias.

I don't get this, but I'm new to Postgres.  Anyway, adding an alias gives me:

```
select avg(totals) as avg_sales 
from (
    select sum(b.quantity * a.price) as total_sales 
    from products a, orderlines b 
    where a.prod_id = b.prod_id group by a.prod_id
) as totals;
```

When I try this, I get:  ERROR:  function avg(record) does not exist

I realize the above code is just getting the overall average sales.  If I can get average sales, then it should be easy to get the products that are above average.

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237244/how-do-i-calculate-the-average-when-the-numbers-are-grouped) will help you.  As I think I asked the same thing you did.

Comment: "Everything I try returns a syntax error" basic common sense to post the exact error

Comment: It helps (I'm trying to be more helpful and less rude as most users seem to be to newcomers) to write out the code that does work.  If you're looking for higher than average dollar sales there's some column names missing.  Plus, how do you determine your average dollar sale?

Comment: You are applying the `avg()` function on the whole **row** that is returned from the derived table. You need to use `select avg(totals.total_sales)`

Answer (score 5):

> *When I try this, I get: ERROR: function avg(record) does not exist*

This is because you are passing the alias of the derived table to the `avg()` function, which means you are passing a complete row (=record) to it, not a single column (value).

To get that working you need to use:

```
select avg(totals.total_sales) as avg_sales 
from (
    select sum(ol.quantity * p.price) as total_sales 
    from products p 
      join orderlines ol on p.prod_id = ol.prod_id
    group by p.prod_id
) as totals;
```

Note that I replaced the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit join with a modern explicit `JOIN` operator. If you are learning SQL you should get used to that syntax.

---

To get the products with a higher than average sale, you need to calculate both: the sales per product **and** the average sale.

This can be achieved by using [a window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) while aggregating:

```
select p.prod_id, 
       sum(ol.quantity * p.price) as total_sales, 
       avg(sum(ol.quantity * p.price)) over () as average_sales
from products p 
  join orderlines ol on p.prod_id = ol.prod_id
group by p.prod_id;
```

This can now be wrapped in a derived table to filter out those with a lower total sales:

```
select *
from (
  select p.prod_id, 
         sum(ol.quantity * p.price) as total_sales, 
         avg(sum(ol.quantity * p.price)) over () as average_sales
  from products p 
    join orderlines ol on p.prod_id = ol.prod_id
  group by p.prod_id
) t
where total_sales >= average_sales;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7f8ab/1

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution and the explanation.  That solves my issue.  By the way it occurred to me suddenly this morning that if we are getting overall average sales based on the total sales of each product, then by definition half of the products are going to have more than average sales, so maybe all I needed to do was rank the products by sales and take the first 50%.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. First using a sub query find the average sales, then get all the products above that sales

```
SELECT p.prod_id, o.quantity
    FROM products p INNER JOIN orderlines o
    ON p.prod_id = o.prod_id
    WHERE o.quantity  >  (      SELECT AVG(ol.quantity)
                                FROM products pr INNER JOIN orderlines ol
                                ON pr.prod_id = ol.prod_id
                        )
```

Comment: Getting error: ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.  Your subquery is returning every product and its average.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you have to remove that group by statement and if you try after that it should work I guess